# MATLAB projectile motion with air resistance

Tags: matlab

I am trying to calculate maximum distance and maximum height of a projectile for an angle theta below.

I assume my way of plotting the graphs of distance against theta and height against theta (on the same graph) are wrong. Any pointers on that will be helpful.

```
e=100;
m = 1;
g = 9.8;
cd = 0.55;
r = 0.02;
p = 1.21;
a = pi*r^2;
v = sqrt((2*e)/m);
k = (1/2)*cd*a*p;

% For loop to calculate Distance and 
for theta = (0:pi/4);

vx = v*cos(theta);

vy = v*sin(theta);

t = sqrt(m/(g*k))*atan(vy*sqrt(k/(m*g)));

x = (m/k)* log((1/vx)+(k/m)*t) - log(1/(vx));

h = (m/k)*(log(cos(atan(vy*sqrt(k/(m*g))-sqrt((g*k)/m)*t))-log(cos((atan(vy*sqrt(k/m*g)))))));

plot (x, theta);

plot (h, theta);

end
```

Comment: Please describe the *exact* error you are getting, and tell us which line it is.

Comment: And what is the value of `t`?

Comment: No for loop needed, make theta a vector from 0 to pi/4 with certain stepsize: theta=[0:0.001:pi/4]

Comment: i have corrected my value of t by adding a line of code. Now i only have a plotting error.

Comment: First aff all you again forgot the stepsize and will thus have only two values in theta, 0 and 1... Second, vysqrt in lines 4 and 6 is missing an operation such as vy *, depending on what you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to loop through different values of theta. Try this instead:

```
theta = (0:0.01:pi/4); % theta = [0 0.01 0.02 0.03 ... pi/4]
vx = v*cos(theta);
vy = v*sin(theta);
t = sqrt(m/(g*k)) * atan(vy .* sqrt(k/(m*g))); % element wise matrix multiplication
x = (m/k)* log((1./vx)+(k/m)*t) - log(1./(vx));
h = (m/k)*(log(cos(atan(vy .* sqrt(k/(m*g))- sqrt((g*k)/m)*t))-log(cos((atan(vy .* sqrt(k/m*g)))))));
plot (x, theta);
plot (h, theta);
```

x vs theta:

[image: x vs theta]

Also try this:

[MATLAB: Creating a Function to Plot Projectile with Drag](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/132561-creating-a-function-to-plot-projectile-with-drag)

[MATLAB: Numerical approximation of projectile motion with air resistance](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/43077-numerical-approximation-of-projectile-motion-with-air-resistance)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The variable `t` is not defined. Also the loop variable should be integer, for example:

```
N = 10;
for i = 0:N-1
   theta = pi/4*i/(N-1)
 (...)
end
```